# not updating a new field in Products on the database in VirtueMart 2

Tags: php, mysql, virtuemart

I have use this guide: http://internet-studio.ca/vm2_new_field.php
to create a new field in the administrator panel.

The difference with the guide is that I created a field in the product_prices.

1. first I created a new column in the table:

   ALTER TABLE `uhhu_virtuemart_product_prices` ADD `prices_gb` DECIMAL(15,2)
2. \administrator\components\com_virtuemart\views\product\tmpl\product_edit_price.php 
   I add this for being show in the administrator

   ">

   product->price_giftbox ?>"/> 
   vendor_currency;   ?>
3. administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini
   I update this with COM_VIRTUEMART_GIFT_BOX and COM_VIRTUEMART_GIFT_BOX_TIP.
4. /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/tables/products.php (from guide)
   mine: /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/tables/product_prices.php

   var $price_gb = null;

but it didn't have something like this to put my price_gb:
Then serach for the follwoing line of code:
$this->setTranslatable(array('product_name','product_s_desc','product_desc','metadesc','metakey','customtitle'));

And I also went to file: administrator/components/com_virtuemart/views/product/view.html.php
and I placed mine at the end.

```
$product_empty_price = array(
'virtuemart_product_price_id' => 0
, 'virtuemart_product_id'         => $virtuemart_product_id
, 'virtuemart_shoppergroup_id'    => NULL
, 'product_price'                 => NULL
, 'override'                      => NULL
, 'product_override_price'        => NULL
, 'product_tax_id'                => NULL
, 'product_discount_id'           => NULL
, 'product_currency'              => $vendor->vendor_currency
, 'product_price_publish_up'      => NULL
, 'product_price_publish_down'    => NULL
, 'price_quantity_start'          => NULL
, 'price_quantity_end'            => NULL
, 'price_giftbox'                 => NULL
);
```

So the result is when I create a new product when I fill all the fields I want and the new field with the price ex. 15
when I press Save it goes 0.00.

And when I change the price from the database with ex. 15, when I refresh the product it show the correct value: 15.

What should I do for updating the database when I press Save button ?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:

To update the price when we press save we go here:

```
administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/product.php
```

We look for the function:

```
public function store (&$product, $isChild = FALSE) {
```

and we search for the PricetoStore list, something like this:

```
if (!$isChild){
                    //$pricesToStore['basePrice'] = $data['mprices']['basePrice'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['product_override_price'] = $data['mprices']['product_override_price'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['override'] = (int)$data['mprices']['override'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['virtuemart_shoppergroup_id'] = (int)$data['mprices']['virtuemart_shoppergroup_id'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['product_tax_id'] = (int)$data['mprices']['product_tax_id'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['product_discount_id'] = (int)$data['mprices']['product_discount_id'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['product_currency'] = (int)$data['mprices']['product_currency'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['product_price_publish_up'] = $data['mprices']['product_price_publish_up'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['product_price_publish_down'] = $data['mprices']['product_price_publish_down'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['price_quantity_start'] = (int)$data['mprices']['price_quantity_start'][$k];
                    $pricesToStore['price_quantity_end'] = (int)$data['mprices']['price_quantity_end'][$k];
```

----->     $pricesToStore['price_gb'] = (int)$data['mprices']['price_giftbox'][$k];
                    }

and just write ours at the end!